# Trying to get the Exchange java libary into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bitcoin

I'm trying to make a bot and was going to use the XChange API to talk to the servers.
I cannot figure out how to set the library up on eclipse.

On the url (git hub)
https://github.com/timmolter/XChange
at the buttom it says
For the latest bugfixes and features you should use the [snapshot jars] (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/knowm/xchange/) or build yourself from the DEVELOP 
I went to the snapshoot page, a buch of links not simply a list of files tro download.
Trying to figure out the best way to get this into eclipse.

Comment: A couple of lines more towards the bottom of said page the author explains how to use the snapshot jars, with Maven. The Sonatype link is a link into a Nexus repository, what you call links are actually directories, and these directories contain the jars. You could of course download them, but using Maven will be so much easier.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I guess now I will have to learn how to use Maven.